# SSRS - can I link the axis of two charts together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, charts

am using SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2010.

[image: two charts with x axis interval set to 1, and y min/max values set to 0 & 700]

I would like to link the y axis of these two charts together, is this possible?

M

Comment: p.s. I mean here that I would like them to scale up and down together (so that in the above case they would both have a max y value of 200).

Answer (score 0):

In the vertical axis properties you can configure the maximum value for the axis with an expression. Then check whichever dataset contains the largest value and set it to that (optionally adding a bit of padding if you need to).

You can check the maximum value of each dataset by scoping the `MAX()` function to the particular dataset.

Your expression for the maximum axis value would look something like this:

```
=IIF(MAX(Fields!c.Value, "DataSet1") > MAX(Fields!c.Value, "DataSet2"), MAX(Fields!c.Value, "DataSet1"), MAX(Fields!c.Value, "DataSet2"))
```

In this case there are two datasets named "DataSet1" and "DataSet2" and they both have a field named `c` which is the value displayed on the chart.

Note: This won't work if you're applying filtering to the data on the chart or you're doing aggregations based on the grouping. There may be a different scoping you can use in that case but I'd have to play around with it to figure it out.